# I cannot traverse through my linked list, after creating an array of nodes

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list

I've created an array of nodes for a linked list however when I attempt to traverse to print my linked list I crash. My traversal works a treat when I do not create an array of nodes so I figure this snippit of code is my problem.

```
   typedef struct node {
book data;
struct node *next;
} *Node;

Node newNodes[100];
int i = 0;
for (i=0; i<n; i++) 
{
    newNodes[i] = (Node)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
    newNodes[i]->next = NULL;
    newNodes[i]->data.time = NULL;
    newNodes[i]->data.format = NULL;     
}


//return struct that holds the array;
```

Clearly I've done something wrong, insert_node is a really simple insert at front algorithm by the way. Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Comment: n is a parameter of the function, chopped some of my code off.

Comment: Is `newNodes` a local variable?  If so, you can't return `newNodes` because it will go out of scope.  If not, please show the entire function.

Comment: It is local. Should I be malloc'ing space for newNodes?

Comment: Yes, you need to.  Like JS1 said, as soon as the method returns `newNodes` (which lives on the stock) disappears.  So what is returned is garbage *and* you have a memory leak since the malloc'd nodes are "stranded" -- they're still allocated but you've lost the pointers to them.

Comment: How do I malloc for on array of nodes then?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: I understand I need to malloc space for my newNodes now, having trouble actually doing that for a struct.

Comment: what you posted is correct for an array of 'empty' linked lists. please post your other code

Comment: Got it working, thanks very much guys. Malloc'd the space for newNodes and I can traverse and insert no problems.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

The posted code shows that you have created 100 pointers and assigned memory to them from the value returned by `malloc`. However, you haven't linked them up together to form a linked list.

Perhaps you meant to use:

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++) 
{
    newNodes[i] = (Node)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
    newNodes[i]->next = NULL;
    newNodes[i]->data.time = NULL;
    newNodes[i]->data.format = NULL;     
}

// Make the links between the nodes.
for (i=0; i<n-1; i++) 
{
   newNodes[i]->next = newNodes[i+1];
}
```

That will make `newNodes[0]` the head of the linked list.

**PS**

Using a `typedef` called `Node` that is a pointer is very confusing, at least to me. I would recommend using:

```
typedef struct node {
    book data;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

typedef Node* NodePtr;
```